# Style custom components using styled-components, React and Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, styled-components

I am building an app using React + Flow, and I'm stuck with a silly issue for styling.

Basically, I have (resumed):

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Item = styled(Link)`
  some styling here
`;
```

and I get the following error from Flow:

```
Cannot call `styled` because:
- Either a callable signature is missing in object type [1].
- Or a callable signature is missing in object type [2].
```

How can I style my own components without having this error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component and render a `Link` and send `this.props.className` to prop `className` of `Link` Component.

You can see `MyLink` component in this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/n03z3oq5vj